# What is faster: append html to an array or use mixed html/php

Tags: php, html, performance, mixed

What is the faster way to output html in PHP that contains PHP variables?

Version A:

```
<div id="example"><?php echo $var; ?></div>
... much more like this
```

or

Version B:

```
$html = array();

$html[] = '<div id ="example">';
$html[] = &$var;
$html[] = '</div>';
$html[] = '... much more like this';

echo implode( '', $html );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it is faster to mix html and php. Version B, will essentially hold a big array in memory, and in the end loop through all the elements. So it will be slower, than just print/echo the data right away. Either way, I won't recommend either approach. I will suggest using a template engine and provide it with data, instead of mixing php and html, this way you can keep markup and logic completely separate. This is often done as a part of a MVC pattern as @Wrong described.

Comment: So is Version A the common way to do this? It looks very unclean.

Comment: Yes, version A is the common way to do this. Anyway, look for my answer above

Comment: @user2429266 If you think this looks unclean, you should take a look at Template engines (i.e. http://www.smarty.net/) which makes you able to seperate php logic and html more neatly.

Comment: @Joren smarty.net is quite big, and has a lot of features which some would say doens't belong in an template engine, I can recommend [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) as template engine, it is small easy extensible, and very fast. If you prefer no kind of logic what so ever in a template language, you could look at [moustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) for php.

Comment: I have a strictly separated logic&template codebase. This concerns just the template files. And they look terrible with the mixed way. Thanks.

Comment: Would you answer this question the same way if someone uses ob_start() ?

Comment: Yes it doesn't really make a difference, in fact a lot of template engines utilizes ob_start in some fashion.

Answer (score 1):

> PHP - Hypertext Pre Processor

In fact, `PHP` is a templating engine itself. In any case variant A is better, but such code isn't the best solution for bigger projects. Try looking on `MVC` design pattern, which will help you separate database/business logic from the representation part of your application. Using an template engine (like `Twig`, `Smarty`, `Blitz` etc.) will help you achieve this too.